# Where can I find documentation on the code in this .s file?

Tags: c, macos, assembly, clang

I produced the assembler below by running

```
clang -s hello.c
```

where `hello.c` is the filename for the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {

printf("Hello\n");

}
```

The assembler is in `hello.s`:

```
  .section  __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
  .build_version macos, 10, 14  sdk_version 10, 14
  .globl  _main                   ## -- Begin function main
  .p2align  4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
  .cfi_startproc
## %bb.0:
  pushq %rbp
...
```

Comment: I think it's called GNU Assembler...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find docs in the GAS manual (clang/LLVM uses the same syntax including directives).  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/

See also links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info for more about x86-64 AT&T syntax.

Clang/LLVM can use Intel syntax, just like GCC, but the directives don't change.  `clang --x86-asm-syntax=intel`, or maybe `-masm=intel` for compatibility with GCC.

There might also be something in the clang or LLVM manual.  (But don't confuse this with [LLVM-IR assembly language](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html): the asm syntax for LLVM's internal representation.)  From a quick search, I didn't find any LLVM docs for how `clang` handles GAS directives.

---

`.globl  _main` is *not* the label itself.  Notice that it's before the alignment padding.  It's just an attribute modifier for the symbol `_main`.

`_main:` is the position in the output file that the label is applied to.

For understanding the instructions, see [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) for how to strip out irrelevant directives.

Comment: Hey, I was starting to finally stumble across some links on Google. Thanks for your input! And the extra links and info.

Comment: Note that this is on macOS. I'm not sure if they use a special assembler there.

Comment: @fuz: Pretty sure it's still clang/LLVM.  IDK if they patch it to add any special directives.  I wondered about `.build_version`

Comment: @PeterCordes I know that clang ships a reimplementation of GNU as these days.

Comment: @fuz: Pretty sure that's just clang, running clang/LLVM's built-in assembler.  Exactly like you get on Linux if you run `clang -c foo.s`.  Not sure if [Installing GNU Assembler in OSX](//stackoverflow.com/q/1712331) is out of date, but the answers there report that GNU binutils `as` can't create MachO64 object files.  OTOH I've also seen a report that GNU binutils `objdump` (`gobjdump` on a mac after installing it from macports apparently) does work: [Disassemble into x86\_64 on OSX10.6 (But with \_Intel\_ Syntax)](//stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/5304301)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's called GNU Assembler, and I found documentation for it here: https://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.12/as.info/index.html.